# How to replace string in unix shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have one file with following details

```
EMP_name=XYZ
EMP_id=123
Emp_contact=123456

EMP_name=abc
EMP_id=456
Emp_contact=123456

EMP_name=lmn
EMP_id=789
Emp_contact=123456

EMP_name=pqr
EMP_id=234
Emp_contact=123456
```

I want to update the `emp_id` of all employee from another CSV file
like for `EMP_name=abc` -> `Emp_id=123456`

Please tell me how to solve this problem

Comment: Use `awk`. Please post a sample of the other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F '=' '/EMP_name/{if($2 == "abc") $0="EMP_name=abcdefg"}{print $0}' input.txt > output.txt
```

may help you. You just need to replace the "abs" and "abcdefg"